# How to extract Google Analytics data using PHP Curl

Tags: php, json, curl, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there any way by which we can extract Google analytic data using PHP script? I wish to get data in JSON format.

Comment: Well, there is a documentation for that platform published by google. We assume you read that. What does it say?

Comment: can u share me the link.

Comment: Googleing for "google analytics api" delivers the first three hits to be exactly what you are looking for. In there you will find: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Comment: Thanks @arkascha. It worked for me & I am able to fetch the data from GA using service account method.